# How do I run a python script during the installation process of a python package?

Tags: python, package

So basically during the installation process of my package, I want a python script to run which will run a .sql file.  If I just include the python script in the `setup.py` file under `scripts=['.../script.py']` and the `.sql file` under 
`package_data = {'pckg': ['data/*.sql']}` would it automatically run the script during installation?  Or would I have to do it manually afterwards?

Comment: I suggest doing it manually afterwards and have README instructions for post-installation command. It is possible to run arbitrary commands on `setup.py install`, but highly not recommended. Instead, let `setup.py` deploy a shell script and then ask the user to run this script afterwards.